# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'getBottles' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x

I get a localError:local variable 'getBottles' referenced before assignment, in python 3.
I don't really understand what I am doing wrong. What does it mean by referenced before assignment

```
# Lab 5-4 The Bottle Return Program

#the main function
def main():
    endProgram = 'no'

    while endProgram == 'no':
        totalBottles = getBottles()
        totalPayout = calPayout (totalBottles)
        printInfo (totalBottles, totalPayout)

        #this function will get the number of bottles returned
        def getBottles():
            totalBottles = 0
            todayBottles = 0
            counter = 1
            while counter <= 7:
                todayBottles = input('Enter number of bottles for today: ')
                totalBottles = totalBottles + todayBottles
                counter = + 1
                return totalBottles

        #this function calculates the pay out amount   
        def calcPayout(totalBottles):
            totalPayout = 0
            totalPayout = totalBottles * 0.10
            return totalPayout

        #this funciton displays the results
        def printInfo (totalBottles, totalPayout):
            print('The total number of bottles collected is ', totalBottles)
            print('The total paid out is $', totalPayout)


    endProgram = input('Do you want to end the program? (Enter yes or no): ')

#calls main
main()
```

Comment: It means you are calling function named `getbottles()` before it is even assigned since, first line after while calls the function but definition of function is later.

Comment: Push `def getBottles()` and all other function right next to `def main()`

Answer (score 0):

In python you have to define functions before you use them, meaning at a lower line number in the document. This is closer to the code you want:

```
def getBottles():
    totalBottles = 0
    todayBottles = 0
    counter = 1
    while counter <= 7:
        todayBottles = input('Enter number of bottles for today: ')
        totalBottles = totalBottles + todayBottles
        counter = + 1
        return totalBottles



#this function calculates the pay out amount   
def calcPayout(totalBottles):
    totalPayout = 0
    totalPayout = totalBottles * 0.10
    return totalPayout

#this funciton displays the results
def printInfo (totalBottles, totalPayout):
    print('The total number of bottles collected is ', totalBottles)
    print('The total paid out is $', totalPayout)


def main():
    endProgram = 'no'

    while endProgram == 'no':
        totalBottles = getBottles()
        totalPayout = calPayout (totalBottles)
        printInfo (totalBottles, totalPayout)
        endProgram = input('Do you want to end the program? (Enter yes or no): ')

#calls main
main()
```

Comment: In Python "before you use them" is actually about _time_, not space; a call inside another function doesn't count until that function is _called_.  This allows important things like mutual recursion, but it doesn't allow the code in the question because the definition _and_ the use happen while `main` is running.